# how to redirect the page to specific url who we obtain from response [get by sending ajax request]

Tags: javascript, ajax

my javascript code send a request and get the ID who created by user and unique. now i want to show detailed of using ID.

the ID  i obtain through ajax request. tell me why this code not wait for response and gone without running whole statement i passed using if else condition

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "/home/ajax",
                        global: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({ fname: fname, mname: mname, lname: lname, phone: phone, land: land, address: add, district: dist, city: city, state: state, pincode: pincode }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.result) {
                                var groupID = data.groupID;
                               document.location = "home/ajax_add/" + groupID;
                            }
                            else
                                $("#errorgroup").append(data.message);
                        }
                    });
```

the code not wait for response and gone out from the block forget if and else who i write on them.

how i can do something then they wait for id and redirect the page i specify in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In syncronous mode you don't have method.

change it as follow:

```
var myResponse = $.ajax({
    url: "/home/ajax",
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: ({ fname: fname, mname: mname, lname: lname, phone: phone, land: land, address: add, district: dist, city: city, state: state, pincode: pincode }),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
});
```

Then you manage your response variable (myResponse) as you want.